# appSetting.Development.json not injected during Debug on ASP.Net Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following in my `appSetting.json`;

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MailServiceSettings": {
    "SmtpServer": "<server>",
    "ToAddresses": [
      "email@domain.com",
      "email2@domain.com"
    ],
    "UserName": "username",
    "Password": "password"
  }
}
```

and in `appSettings.Development.json` i have a subtle change;

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MailServiceSettings": {
    "SmtpServer": "<server>",
    "ToAddresses": [
      "development@domain.com"
    ],
    "UserName": "username",
    "Password": "password"
  }
}
```

This is so I can text the mail sender settings in my localhost without bombarding the live mailbox.

However, when I run in debug the settings from `appSettings.json` are being injected insted of the `appSettings.Development.json`.

My `Program.cs` is using the default `WebHostBuilder`;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
}
```

and setup the DI as following in my `StartUp.cs`;

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.Configure<MailServiceSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MailServiceSettings"));

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }
```

Then when I debug and break on the configuration I can see that the `appSettings.Development.json` have been read (as I can drill down into the `Configuration` sections when debugging I can see they are added as an additional entry, and I believe `WebHost.CreateDefaultbuilder` adds the `env.EnvironmentName` files by default).

However, when I then instantiate an controller method;

```
public ContactController(IOptions<MailServiceSettings> mailSettings, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _mailSettings = mailSettings;
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}
```

I am finding that the 2x email address from the `appSettings.json` are injected instead of the `appSettings.Development.json`

I have also checked `env.IsDevelopment()` at runtime and this is returning `true`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Check both files' properties. Is option `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy Always` in `Advanced` section?

Comment: From further tests it seems that `appSettings.json` is overriding the development version, for example if I remove the 2x email address completely from `appSettings.json` the 1x email address is injected from the `appSettings.Developement.json` is this correct?

Comment: It's wierd. Did you set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value in `Properties/defaultSettings.json`? Or in your host environment variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm having trouble tracking down and official source for this, but essentially the issue is that `IConfiguration` is basically a dictionary and the keys and values from configuration sources are flattened into that. In other words, at the end of the day, what you're actually getting is something like the following in pseudo-code:

```
["MailServiceSettings:ToAddresses[0]"] = "email@domain.com"
["MailServiceSettings:ToAddresses[1]"] = "email2@domain.com"
```

Then, when your `appsettings.Development.json` config comes in:

```
["MailServiceSettings:ToAddresses[0]"] = "development@domain.com"
```

In other words, you still have two items in the config. The only way around this is to have settings like this only in your environment-specific config. If you remove this from `appsettings.json` entirely and then do:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MailServiceSettings": {
    "SmtpServer": "<server>",
    "UserName": "username",
    "Password": "password"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "MailServiceSettings": {
    "ToAddresses": [
      "development@domain.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Production.json**

```
{
  "MailServiceSettings": {
    "ToAddresses": [
      "email@domain.com",
      "email2@domain.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, you'll correctly only have the one address in development and the two in production.